# Independent sub σ-algebra measured by the same random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},Pr)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be two sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose that they are independent, and suppose that  is real valued random variable on $\Omega$ which is measurable with respect to both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. Show that  is almost surely constant; that is there is real number $c \in \mathbb{R}$, so that $Pr(X=c)=1$.

Firstly, I am not sure what independent $\sigma$-algebra means here and how I can connect the independence of $\sigma$-algebra with random variable.

Secondly, since $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are different $\sigma$-algebra, is it allowed to be measured by the same random variable? What does this imply? Maybe my question is a little bit vague, but I always think that different $\sigma$-algebra should be measured by different random variable somehow. And I don't even know why I take it as granted.

There is a solution somewhere. But I feel it makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Consider $A= [X \le \alpha]$, this is both ${\cal F,G}$ measurable and they are independent so
$P[A \cap A] = P[A]= P[A]^2$, and the only solutions are $0,1$. What does this say about the distribution function of $X$?

Answer (score 5):

- $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ being independent means $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = P(A_1) P(A_2)$ for any $A_1 \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A_2 \in \mathcal{G}$.
- $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ being measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ means that for any Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the preimage $X^{-1}(B)$ is in both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. It is not unreasonable for a random variable to be measurable with respect to different sigma-algebras. For instance, a constant random variable is measurable with respect to any sigma-algebra.

Let $c_1 \ne c_2$ and let $A_1 = X^{-1}(\{c_1\})$ and $A_2 = X^{-1}(\{c_2\})$. What is $A_1 \cap A_2$? What does that say about $P(X=c_1)$ and $P(X=c_2)$?